# Tensorflow Dataset performances?

Tags: performance, tensorflow

I am implementing a model inspired by the [NMT](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt) model. I am using a training set stored as TFRecords files, using a TFRecordDataset to fetch it and feed the model. Following Google's [recommendations](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#input_pipeline_optimization) about input pipeline performances improvement, I have:

- preprocessed as much as possible beforehand on CPU
- stacked several training examples up to about 100 MB TFrecords files (having less files containing more examples)
- used `num_parallel_calls` and `prefetch` on the Dataset `map` operations.

However, GPU remains at maximum 40%, and it is barely as slow as when run on CPU. I am thus wondering about the `prefetch` operation.

- If I understand correctly, it will create a special thread that buffers *N* examples. But what does it mean ? What happens to the other examples not buffered ?
- is there an optimal relation between the prefetch buffer size, the number of examples in the complete Dataset and the batch size ? In the NMT code, prefetch buffer size is set at `1000*batch_size`, but why ? If e.g. I am using 10000 examples, a batch size of 100, what should be the prefetch buffer size ?

Any other advice regarding Dataset speedup would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Dataset API runs on [CPU and not on GPU](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610), so this answers the question.